# If $G$ is a finite group such that every maximal subgroup is nilpotent, are any two maximal subgroups of $G$ conjugate?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups, maximal-subgroup

I’m trying to prove that if every maximal subgroup of a finite group $G$ is nilpotent, then $G$ is solvable. I know already that if any two maximal subgroups of a finite group are conjugate, then it is cyclic, so it is solvable. So my question is:

If $G$ is a finite group such that every maximal subgroup is nilpotent, are any two maximal subgroups of $G$ conjugate?

I’m using the following definition of “nilpotent group”: $G$ has a lower central series terminating in the trivial subgroup after finitely many steps.

Comment: Are you aware of https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Schmidt-Iwasawa_theorem  ?

Comment: In $S_3$, every maximal subgroup is nilpotent (in fact, abelian), but you have maximal subgroups of order $3$ and maximal subgroups of order $2$, which cannot be conjugate.

Comment: @ahulpke No, I wasn’t! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a counterexample, let $G$ be any non-cyclic finite abelian group.

Since $G$ is abelian, every maximal subgroup of $G$ is abelian, hence nilpotent.

Since $G$ is a non-cyclic finite abelian group, $G$ has more than one maximal subgroup, no two of which are conjugate (in an abelian group, no two distinct subgroups are conjugate to each other).